# How to use IF statement insde FOR loop in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

[image: data base]I used if condition inside for loop. I'm trying to display messages if condition is satisfied, condition is not satisfied don't want to display. Help me in that.

views.py

```
username = request.session['username']
sent_msg = Message.objects.filter(sender= username).values()
for i in sent_msg:
    print(i.sender)
    print(i.message)
return render(request, 'mes.html',{'sent_msg': sent_msg})
```

msg.html

```
{% for i in sent_msg %}
   {% if i.action_view == 0 %}
        <p>{{ i.sender }}</p>
        <p>{{ i.recipient }}</p>
        <p>{{ i.message }}</p>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here i'm trying to display data when if condition satisfied, otherwise it display nothing. I tried in this way but its not displaying anything.

Comment: `print(i.action_view)` and see what it prints.The message is not displaying because the condition is not satisfied

Comment: it's printing action_view data i tried that

Comment: is `action_view` actually `0` ?

Comment: is it equals to 0

Comment: `i.action_view == 0` will be false if `i.action_view` is not an integer. Maybe try comparing with a string value:  `i.action_view == '0'`.

Comment: @xyres what if it actually returns `0` as an int

Comment: what i would do in his case is testing the objects in the `views.py` as @user11418935 said, and i dont think in `views.py` you say `i.sender` instead its `i['sender']` because django returns dict not attributes

Comment: @Moha369 in action_view column have data like 1 and 0 i want to print message which action_view is 0

Comment: @Kumar can you show your `Message`model

Comment: @user11418935 i want to display message where action_view is 0. action_view column data is 0 and 1. I want to print only where action_view is 0

Comment: try to print the messages without the if just testing if you even have anything in the model or not, and sometimes you have to shut down the server and run it again, so everything is possible.

Comment: @Moha369 i have added picture of that

Comment: @Moha369 Its printing message without if condition. But i want pass condition there

Comment: as i see in the picture, its `sender_use` not `sender` as you filtered in `views.py`

Comment: It's often useful when debugging to insert an HTML comment above a conditional that is misbehaving, f.ex. `<!-- actionview: {{i.actionview}} -->`. Then  just view page source in browser. Django template substitution does not skip HTML comments.

Comment: @Kumar Is `action_view` and integer or a string? Check using `print(type(i.action_view))`.

Comment: Thanks all now i fixed @xyres told its not `{% if i.action_view == 0 %} its `{% if i.action_view == 0 %}` and its working fine now

Comment: @xyres it holds str value this is why its not displaying anything. now i used str now working fine. Thank you